# Is there any function in oracle to keep a string length fixed?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario like when a column value exceeds the length of 10 characters, I need to take a sub-string for only 10 characters (left most) but if it is shorter than that it should be left padded with zeroes. I tried the following:

`with data1 as (select '1234567890123' as dummy1 from dual)
select CASE when (length(dummy1)>10) then substr(dummy1,1,10) else lpad(dummy1,10,'0') end from data1;`

But this seems to me quite a longer way to do. Is there any shorter way to achieve this, maybe an Oracle function?

I tried to Google this but could not find any relevant result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lpad is enough to do the job :

`SELECT LPAD( '1234567890123', 10, '0' ) AS formatted
FROM   dual;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SUBSTR` and `LPAD` together:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '1234567890123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LPAD( SUBSTR( value, 1, 10 ), 10, '0' ) AS formatted
FROM   data;
```

**Output**:

```
FORMATTED
----------
1234567890
0000000001
```